proportional odds ratio using gtsummary
I'm trying to produce a univariate regression table with a 4-level response variable using VGAM package.
But I get the error described below. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?
This is the code:
    tbl_uvregression(
    method = vglm,
    y = Y,
    method.args = list(family = cumulative(parallel=TRUE) ),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    hide_n = TRUE,
    tidy_fun = broom.helpers::tidy_parameters,
    pvalue_fun = label_style_pvalue(digits = 3),
    )
 

and this is the error:
    Error in `tibble::tibble()`:
! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
* Size 4: Existing data.
* Size 2: Column `variable`.
i Only values of size one are recycled.

